# Ubuntu 16.04 can't connect with internet after change additional drivers

Tags: networking, internet

[SOLVE]
I have an issue after change additonal driver to nvidia graphic i can't access website on chrome but i can ping 8.8.8.8. and connect with my wifi.
I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: OK, you can ping 8.8.8.8. But can you ping, say, www.google.com?

Comment: @Barafu Albino i cant ping www.google.com, i dont know why??

Comment: That means DNS not working. Try to edit file `/etc/resolv.conf`, replace whatever nameserver there is by `nameserver 8.8.8.8` line and see if Internet starts to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with DHCP - it does not set proper DNS address. As a workaround, go to System Settings - > Network Settings -> Options and on IPv4 tab set your DNS address to 8.8.8.8 or whatever DNS server you want to use.
Manual edits to /etc/resolv.conf are not persistant - they last untill update only.